# use google map api in android app and add marker of particular location using lat long

Tags: android

I am building an android app which needs to show map and marker of particular village from where user logins into the app.so i want to get the current location of the user and show it as marker in the form of google map and the full address of the user onto it.

Comment: Please show a specific problem - code you have tried and how the output differs from what you expect.

Comment: Please view this: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker

Comment: have a look this https://github.com/ErNaveen/GoogleMapExample/blob/master/src/com/example/mapdemo/CircleDemoActivity.java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use google map api v2 or v3.
1.Use google play service library in your project.
2.use reverse geocoder to find the address from latitude and longitude and show it in the marker of the 
  google map shown.

```
 Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(context, Locale.getDefault());
                String result = null;
                try {
                    List<Address> addressList = geocoder.getFromLocation(
                            latitude, longitude, 1);
                    if (addressList != null && addressList.size() > 0) {
                        Address address = addressList.get(0);
                        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                        for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                            sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append("\n");
                        }
                        sb.append(address.getLocality()).append("\n");
                        sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append("\n");
                        sb.append(address.getCountryName());
                        result = sb.toString();
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "Unable connect to Geocoder", e);
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

This code is used to get the current location.

```
double lat;
double lng;

mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,10000,
                    1, mLocationListener);
private final LocationListener mLocationListener = new LocationListener() {


        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

            lat = location.getLatitude();
            lng = location.getLongitude();
            Toast.makeText(MapActivity.this, lat+"" + lng +" ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    };
```

Now OnLocationChanged() method gives you the current lat and lng. save these lat and lng as instance variable.

To show the marker of current location into map use this code

```
static final LatLng HAMBURG = new LatLng(lat, lng);
map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(HAMBURG );
```

and all the permission in manifest file

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```